# Renaming Custom Taxonomy Values

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, customization, bulk

I'm new to Wordpress and have been tasked to migrate an existing non-Wordpress site to Wordpress.

Our original site has each page associated to a country. I've been reading a lot and I believe I need to create a custom post type ("Country Pages") and a custom taxonomy ("Country").

The problem I have is with updating countries in the long term (ex. "China" to be renamed to "Republic of China").

With custom PHP sites, I would have a separate country "meta" table with the ff. columns:

- country_id
- country_name
- country_description

and associate each page to a country_id.  Updating the country_name will only be done in one row of the table and the pages will automatically have the updated country_name.

With Wordpress however, since taxonomy values (country_names) are directly specified in the meta box and not taxonomy ids (country_id), would I be forced to update all pages when I need to update the taxonomy value?  Can a taxonomy be structured similar to a table and not just as a single value?

Feel free to edit my question since I'm not too familiar with Wordpress terminologies. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom taxonomy (Country) to your custom post type (Country Pages) and are connected through their ids.
Updating the name of a taxonomy will affect all Country Pages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I didn't see that there are in fact taxonomy edit screens which are added automatically.